# regex to replace regular quotes with curly quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a block of text where the opening and closing quotes are same

***"Hey", How are you? "Hey there"... “Some more text” and some more "here".***

Please note that the quote character is " and not “ ” these characters

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

I want to replace the opening " character as “

it will now look as
***“Hey", How are you? “Hey there"... “Some more text” and some more “here".***

and then again running I can simply find and replace the left over " occurance as ”

and that would give the expected output which should look as

***“Hey”, How are you? “Hey there”... “Some more text” and some more “here”.***

Comment: You should use a capture group for the text between quotes. Then you can replace the whole match with an opening curly quote, the captured group, and a closing curly quote.

Comment: I need to undergo this in 2 steps, firstly I would like to replace opening " and then closing " in two separate operations. This is needed due to the drawback of my existing system (I am reverse engineering the code)

Comment: So, you want `text = text.replace(/"([^"]*")/g, "“")` and then `text = text.replace(/"/g, "”")` instead of just `text.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "“$1”")`?

Comment: @Wiktor, don't you mean, `text = text.replace(/"([^"]*")/g, "“"+$1)`?  Pardon the syntax of `"“"+$1` if it's incorrect.

Comment: The `$1` means group#1 @CarySwoveland, and `replace` will replace it internally. So [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/) syntax is completely right: ``'hi "Man"'.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "“$1”")`` --> `hi “Man”`

Comment: @MMMahdy-PAPION, I was just looking at what Wiktor was suggesting, which is in the first line.  He said *instead of* `text.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "“$1”")`, which replaces all double-quotes at once, but `text.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, '“$1"')` would work too.

Comment: @CarySwoveland oh that one, you are right. His first syntax should be like what you said.

Comment: Sure,  I lost the `$1`  somewhere in the first code part, `text = text.replace(/"([^"]*")/g, "“$1")`. No need to move `$1` out of the string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be for the solution given by @WiktorStribiżew in a comment on the question, but I wish to give an alternative solution that may be of interest to some readers.

The second replacement of the remaining (trailing) double-quotes (i.e., ASCII 32) is straightforward, so I will not discuss that.

You could match leading double-quotes with the following regular expression, and then replace each match with `“`:

```
"(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o1PBjf/1)

This regex is based on the observation that we want to identify all double-quotes that are followed later in the string by an odd number of double-quotes (assuming the string contains an even number of double-quotes.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
"              # match a double-quote (dq)
(?=            # begin a positive lookahead
  (?:          # begin a non-capture group
    (?:        # begin a non-capture group
      [^"]*"   # match 0+ chars other than dq then match dq
    ){2}       # end non-capture group and execute it twice
  )*           # end non-capture group and execute it 0+ times
  [^"]*"[^"]*  # match dq preceded and followed by 0+ non-dq chars
  $            # match end of string
)              # end positive lookahead
```

If the data set is large it may be advisable to perform some benchmarking to see if execution speed is satisfactory.